# Qgis Plugin spectral library tools : AttributeError type object 'QgsMapLayerProxyModel' has no attribute 'Filters'

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, attributeerror

I work with unbuntu 22.04.03 LTS. And Qgis 3.34.0-Prizren. I installed the last version of the plugin spectral library tools.
But when i try to enable it via the plugin manager interface, i get a error message saying :

````
```
Impossible de charger l'extension 'spectral_libraries' provoque une erreur lors de l'appel à sa méthode classFactory()AttributeError: type object 'QgsMapLayerProxyModel' has no attribute 'Filters'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/spectral_libraries/__init__.py", line 14, in classFactory
    from spectral_libraries.spectral_libraries_plugin import SpectralLibrariesPlugin
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/spectral_libraries/spectral_libraries_plugin.py", line 29, in
    from spectral_libraries.interfaces.spectral_library_gui import SpectralLibraryWidget
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/spectral_libraries/interfaces/spectral_library_gui.py", line 28, in
    from spectral_libraries.qps.layerproperties import VectorLayerTools
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/spectral_libraries/qps/layerproperties.py", line 85, in
    from .classification.classificationscheme import ClassificationScheme
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/spectral_libraries/qps/classification/classificationscheme.py", line 44, in
    from ..utils import gdalDataset, nextColor, findMapLayer, registeredMapLayers, loadUi
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/spectral_libraries/qps/utils.py", line 2402, in
    class SelectMapLayersDialog(QgsDialog):
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/spectral_libraries/qps/utils.py", line 2403, in SelectMapLayersDialog
    class LayerDescription(object):
  File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/spectral_libraries/qps/utils.py", line 2405, in LayerDescription
    def __init__(self, info: str, filters: QgsMapLayerProxyModel.Filters, allowEmptyLayer=False):
AttributeError: type object 'QgsMapLayerProxyModel' has no attribute 'Filters'

Version de Python : 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0]
Version de QGIS : 3.34.0-Prizren Prizren, ffbdd678812

Chemin Python :

/usr/share/qgis/python

/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python

/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins

/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins

/usr/lib/python310.zip

/usr/lib/python3.10

/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python

/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/HCMGIS/forms

/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SentinelHub/external/requests_oauthlib-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/go2streetview

/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/go2streetview/res
```
````

Comment: Any update for this? I have almost the exact same problem, same QGIS version, same OS, same python. Though the error occured while installing a different plugin (Enmap-Box 3)